# MCPE: /give command error

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I found out that on the MCPE 1.2 update, Mojang added components to commands. But when I try to enter

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {
display: {
    Name: "Sword of Ethania",
    Lore: [
        "Legendary",
        "The Guardian Sword that defends Ethania"
    ]
},
ench: [
    {
        id: 16,
        lvl: 1
    },
    {
        id: 17,
        lvl: 1
    },
    {
        id: 18,
        lvl: 1
    },
    {
        id: 19,
        lvl: 1
    },
    {
        id: 20,
        lvl: 1
    },
    {
        id: 32,
        lvl: 1
    },
    {
        id: 34,
        lvl: 1
    }
],
HideFlags: 1,
Unbreakable: 1
}
```

then I get this error message:

```
*Line 1 Column 2
Missing '}' or object member name
```

Please help me debug, I have found nothing wrong in the command.
Minimized Version:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name:"Sword of Ethania",Lore:["Legendary","The Guardian Sword that defends Ethania"]},ench:[{id:16,lvl:1},{id:17,lvl:1},{id:18,lvl:1},{id:19,lvl:1},{id:20,lvl:1},{id:32,lvl:1},{id:34,lvl:1}],HideFlags:1}
```

Comment: This is in a command block, by the way

Comment: @Codingale please refrain from answering questions on comments (and consider moving your comment to an answer).

Comment: This is a valid question. There is very little explicit documentation detailing the reason why in Minecraft Bedrock Edition, they can't do much!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wrapping the keys in quotes like `"key":"value"`

Here's the formatted code:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {
    "display": {
        "Name": "Sword of Ethania",
        "Lore": [
            "Legendary",
            "The Guardian Sword that defends Ethania"
        ]
    },
    "ench": [{
            "id": 16,
            "lvl": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "lvl": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "lvl": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 19,
            "lvl": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "lvl": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 32,
            "lvl": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 34,
            "lvl": 1
        }
    ],
    "HideFlags": 1,
    "Unbreakable": 1
}
```

Comment: Can I inquire why exactly this was voted down? By the JSON standard it's technically required to have the keys in quotes under RFC 4627, RFC 7159 and even ECMA-404.

Comment: It's most likely down voted since Bedrock/mcpe does not support Json components besides those commented upon by Plagiatus.

Comment: Also, after performing these changes, the error message changes to a more informative message!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but in case anyone refers to this in the future:

As of the latest mcpe version (`1.2.10`) the only components that have been added to the game are `can_place_on` and `can_destroy`. all other modifications (names, lore) have to be done through external editors or afterwards ingame through the `enchant` command.

**Thus what you're trying to do with this command is currently impossible.**