# /give an enchanted sword results in 'Component was not an object' error in Bedrock/Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm attempting to give a player an enchanted sword using the following command:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {"ench":[{"id":5,"lvl":1}]}
```

Why do I see this error?

This copied from example for Bedrock Edition, but not working.

[image: Command Block]

Comment: where did you copy that example from?

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/318552/mcpe-give-command-error

Comment: that's what I thought. the person in that thread expected pe to just take over all the NBT from java. that is sadly currently not possible in pe as the only supported components are `can_place_on` and `can_break` as @Pepijn pointed out in this answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "components" supported are `can_place_on` and `can_break`. Nothing else.
You will have to externally edit items (MCC Toolchest PE, Universal Minecraft editor, etc.) or just enchant them ingame.

Comment: What this? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/318552/mcpe-give-command-error

Comment: Help please, link to example here

Comment: There are no votes on that answer there. Maybe that person only knows Java Edition.

Comment: @Megafox That post has been clarified with a better answer now.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to use this command, as there is no NBT access, except for the `can_place_on` and `can_break` tags. This is quite upsetting, as I wish to use commands on my switch to recieve a God Bow (`/give @p minecraft:bow{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"God Bow\"}",Lore:["The Best Bow in The World!","Will Shoot Zeus's Lightning Bolts!"]},Unbreakable:1b,Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:power",lvl:100000},{id:"minecraft:punch",lvl:100000},{id:"minecraft:flame",lvl:100000},{id:"minecraft:infinity",lvl:1},{id:"minecraft:mending",lvl:100000}]} 1`). I really hope Mojang AB Updates that soon.